# Illegal offset type error in exporting to excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to export an excel but when i export it, it gives me an error of Illegal offset type error. How can i make it work?
Heres my code in my UsersController.

```
public function userExport()
{
$users = $this->users->paginate(
            $perPage = 20,
            Input::get('search'),
            Input::get('status'),
            Input::get('emp_status'),
            Input::get('level'),
            Input::get('age'),
            Input::get('gender'),
            Input::get('civil_status'),
            Input::get('role_id'),
            Input::get('birthmonth'),
            Input::get('company'),
            Input::get('branches'),
            Input::get('benefit'),
            Input::get('designation'),
            Input::get('tenure')
            // Input::get('gender')
        );
        return Excel::create('data_function',function($excel) use ($users){
            $excel->sheet('mysheet', function($sheet) use ($users){
                $sheet->fromArray($users);
            });
        })->download('xls');
    }
```

Comment: Help me experts

Comment: Hi I'm just talking to no one

Comment: How do u know the error belongs ro tgis code

Comment: Because of the fromArray? Where do you think is the error? @MahdiYounesi

Comment: Coud you dd $users and show me the result

Comment: How to do the dd? @MahdiYounesi

Comment: Please include the text of the error you are receiving as well as a log or stack trace if possible.

Comment: I think that You are passing paginator object `$users` not array.

Comment: show the full error message

Comment: @mrabbani yes is it possible?

Comment: @Sohel0415 the error message is just "ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Illegal offset type"

Comment: // Add seperate values
        else
        {
            $this->data[$key] = $value;
        }

thats the error in "/home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/Classes/LaravelExcelWorksheet.php" @btl

Comment: I tried dd and it showed me like this@MahdiYounesi

Comment: LengthAwarePaginator {#807 ▼
  #total: 1
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#802 ▶}
  #perPage: 20
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://vcy-backup-jamesfrancisramos7.c9users.io/export"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}

@MahdiYounesi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets do this :

this worked for me so i tried this for u please check if any change is needed for u .

```
        //Initialize the array which will be passed into the Excel generator

    $userarray= [];

        // Define the Excel spreadsheet headers

    $userarray[] = ['id', 'search','status','any_thing u_want'];

        // Convert each member of the returned collection into an array,

       // and append it to the payments array.

     foreach ($users as $user) {
       $userarray[] = $user->toArray();
     }

     // Generate and return the spreadsheet

    Excel::create('payments', function($excel) use ($userarray) {

    // Set the spreadsheet title, creator, and description

    $excel->setTitle('users');
    $excel->setCreator('Laravel')->setCompany('any_name, LLC');
    $excel->setDescription('info file');

    // Build the spreadsheet, passing in the payments array

    $excel->sheet('sheet1', function($sheet) use ($userarray) {
        $sheet->fromArray($userarray, null, 'A1', false, false);
    });

})->download('xlsx');
}
```

Comment: whats the $invoicesArray for?

Comment: sorry for that i have edited code . please check if it is any help to you ... and sorry for poor format ... i dont know why it's not showing comment in different color

Comment: what should i put instead of invoicearray?

Comment: check what is inside in userarray after loop

Comment: return (  $userarray ); and check output it throws in network tab in developer mode ctrl+shift+i

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163694/discussion-between-pravin-poudel-and-gwapo).